# ValueError. What does that mean?

Tags: python, opencv

I've been following this tutorial and I'm currently on Project 2 chapter of it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQeoO7MI0Bs&list=WL&index=90&t=9713s.
However when I start implementing the lines of code meant to read values off the image it gives out the following error:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (4,2)

From what I can tell, the error seems to be coming from this function:

```
def reorder(myPoints):
    myPoints = myPoints.reshape((4,2))
    myPointsNew = np.zeros((4,1,2),np.int32)
    add = myPoints.sum(1)
    print("add", add)

    myPointsNew[0] = myPoints[np.argmin(add)]
    myPointsNew[3] = myPoints[np.argmax(add)]
    diff = np.diff(myPoints,axis=1)
    myPointsNew[1] = myPoints[np.argmin(diff)]
    myPointsNew[2] = myPoints[np.argmax(diff)]
    print("New Points", myPointsNew)
```

However the problem is that I followed exactly how I saw on the tutorial and I couldn't come up with a solution. By the way the approximate time frame of this code in the video is at 2:45:00.

Comment: I think `myPoints` is an array of size 0. That's probably why you are getting a value error

Comment: I didn't really initialize myPoints to a specific size so is it automatically 0?